# HttpClient consume Odata Not Working

Tags: xamarin.forms, odata

I use below code to access SAP Odata WebService:

```
     string strUrl = "https://...../HandlingUnitSet?$format=json";

        var credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "usr123");
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();            
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

        var response = await client.GetAsync(strUrl);

        string status = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        string header = response.Headers.ToString();
        string cont = response.Content.ToString();

        string contactsJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

             UoUnit ObjUnitList = new UoUnit();
            ObjUnitList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UoUnit>(contactsJson);
```

The Problem : I got the below error message

The url suppose to return Json Data but I did not get it. This error encountered at the line of DeserializeObject

Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue ()

```
{Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () [0x002b3] in <d32db49e5e3440729da31845c03ddc3a>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () [0x0004c] in <d32db49e5e3440729da31845c03ddc3a>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent () [0x00000] in <d32db49e5e3440729da31845c03ddc3a>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, System.Boolean hasConverter) [0x0004a] in <d32db49e5e3440729da31845c03ddc3a>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, System.Boolean checkAdditionalContent) [0x000db] in <d32db49e5e3440729da31845c03ddc3a>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00054] in <d32db49e5e3440729da31845c03ddc3a>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) [0x00000] in <d32db49e5e3440729da31845c03ddc3a>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (System.String value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x0002d] in <d32db49e5e3440729da31845c03ddc3a>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in <d32db49e5e3440729da31845c03ddc3a>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T] (System.String value) [0x00000] in <d32db49e5e3440729da31845c03ddc3a>:0 
   }
```

Comment: Just looking at the error makes me think that you actually get XML back... Although I cannot say why, as you are making the request correctly for requesting JSON. Can you try to just get the whole response as a string (without parsing the "JSON") to see exactly what you get?

Comment: Inspect what is in the `contactsJson`. It probably has some non-JSON XML or HTML telling you what is wrong.